Any way to speed up buffer exchange between multiprocessing handler and main thread in python?
I would like to implement a handle function to receive and share msg to the main thread for further processing. The latency between the receive time on the handler and the main thread is quite large. I have tried collection.deque and manager.Queue as the buffer but they look the same. The implementation is like this:
def handler(msg):
    global msgBuff
    dict_msg=pickle.loads(msg.data)
    timer=time.time()
    print("handler latency",timer-dict_msg['timestamp'])
    msgBuff.append((dict_msg,time.time()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global msgBuff
    #manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    #msgBuff = manager.Queue()
    msgBuff=collections.deque()
    msg_receiver(handler) # a multiprocessing function to receive message  
    while 1:
        if len(msgBuff)==0:
            time.sleep(0.001)
            continue
        dict_msg,rec_time=msgBuff.popleft()
        print("main latency",time.time()-dict_msg['timestamp'],time.time()-rec_time)


And here is the output
handler latency 0.008012533187866211
main latency 0.022023439407348633 0.014010906219482422
handler latency 0.007892608642578125
main latency 0.023406028747558594 0.015513420104980469
handler latency 0.007999897003173828
main latency 0.02299976348876953 0.013998270034790039
handler latency 0.006999969482421875
main latency 0.02259969711303711 0.015599727630615234
handler latency 0.009000301361083984

Any suggestion of improvement?

collections.deque shouldn't work at all for inter-process communication - if it looks like it does, you might have a bug.

@user2357112 the msg_receiver may be an AIO or multi-thread function. Both manager.Queue() and collections.deque() get the same return

You showed us that elapsed time at certain stages
of processing is roughly 7, 14, or 21 msec.
It appears that serializing / unserializing your data costs about 7 msec,
and you do that more than once.
Shrinking the size of msg.data would allow for faster {ser,deser}ialize.
Consider passing around a data filename rather than the raw data.
Pickle() can sometimes pull in more dependencies than you were expecting.
Consider using an alternate format, perhaps JSON or CSV, that lets
you conveniently examine data to verify it's the amount you expect.
Serializing and deserializing costs time.
Consider using a binary format like pyarrow.
It's even possible to accomplish a zero-copy handoff
to next stage in the pipeline.

They are already the time excluded the serializing/unserializing unless the deque or manager.queue has the serializing/unserializing. 14ms should be the latency between the handler and the main thread

I have tried the PipeQueue below which is much better. Maybe there is a better solution
https://gist.github.com/kylemcdonald/a2f0dcb86f01d4c57b68ac6a6c7a3068
handler latency 0.00800013542175293
main latency 0.00800013542175293 0.0
handler latency 0.008000373840332031
main latency 0.008000373840332031 0.0
handler latency 0.008643627166748047
main latency 0.009168386459350586 0.0005247592926025391

